# c# Windows 10 - Get Notified When Windows Updates are Downloading

Tags: c#, windows-update

I remember back in the Windows 7 days that I would sometimes see a notification that Windows updates are downloading followed some time later by Windows is Installing Updates.

Well, that does not seem to exist on Windows 10. I would like to see if I can create a little program that runs in the background on my machine that will "listen" for those events. It would be nice to know if I can shut down my computer, but I do not want to do that if updates are downloading or installing. Also, I think that Windows Updates get in the way of me installing or updating a program on my computer.

I have done some reading about the Windows Update Agent, but it seems like that is mostly a server tool that allows admins to control which updates get installed and things like that, but I cannot tell if there is anything there that I can use to tell when updates are downloading from Automatic Updates, or even if a user manually starts a download from Windows Update.

So my question is, Is there an event that is triggered, or a property that is set when an update begins downloading and when an update begins installing and finishes installing? Also, which Which Windows Update Agent objects do I need to look at? If someone can point me to the documentation that would be great. Like I said, I have looked at the Windows Update Agent documentation but I didn't see anything there. Thanks, David.